# is It possible to compare two Months Data in single Collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection database with 10 000 000 call records.
I want to compare call usage of previous month to next month.

Example of collection document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ed74d76c68d23af73e230a"),
    "msisdn" : "9818441000",
    "callType" : "ISD"
    "duration" : 10.109999656677246,
    "charges" : 200,
    "traffic" : "Voice",
    "Date" : ISODate("2014-01-05T19:51:01.928Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ed74d76c68d23af73e230b"),
    "msisdn" : "9818843796",
    "callType" : "Local",
    "duration" : 1,
    "charges" : 150,
    "traffic" : "Voice",
    "Date" : ISODate("2014-02-04T14:25:35.861Z")
```

}

Duration is my usage.

I want to compare duration of `ISODate("2014-01-04T14:25:35.861Z")` with next month `ISODate("2014-02-04T14:25:35.861Z")` of all records.

All `msisdn` number are same in both months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious call here seems to be to aggregate the data, which in MongoDB the aggregation framework is well suited to. Taking the general use case fields that I see present here. And yes, we generally talk in terms of discrete months rather than some value assumed to be one month from the current point in time:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "msisdn": "9818441000",
        "Date": {
            "$gte": new Date("2014-01-01"),
            "$lt": new Date("2014-03-01")
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$Date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$Date" },
            "callType": "$callType",
            "traffic": "$traffic"
        },
        "charges": { "$sum": "$charges" },
        "duration": { "$sum": "$duration" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

The intent there is to produce two records in the response representing each month as a distinct value.

You can basically take those two results and compare the difference between them in client code.

Or you can do this over all "MSISDN" values with months grouped into pairs within the document:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "Date": {
            "$gte": new Date("2014-01-01"),
            "$lt": new Date("2014-03-01")
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$Date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$Date" },
            "msisdn": "$msisdn",
            "callType": "$callType",
            "traffic": "$traffic"
        },
        "charges": { "$sum": "$charges" },
        "duration": { "$sum": "$duration" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "msisdn": "$_id.msisdn",
            "callType": "$_id.callType",
            "traffic": "$_id.traffic"
        },
        "data": { "$push": {
            "year": "$_id.year",
            "month": "$_id.month",
            "charges": "$charges",
            "duration": "$duration"
        }}
    }}
])
```

Comment: @Niel Lunn Thanks for Answer but i want to compare all MSISDN not only one MSISDN


it gives my Output like this 


{ "_id" : { "year" : 2014, "month" : 2, "day" : 10, "callType" : "NA", "traffic" : "Data" }, "charges" : 302900, "duration" : 13902.000002503395 }

{ "_id" : { "year" : 2014, "month" : 2, "day" : 11, "callType" : "NA", "traffic" : "Data" }, "charges" : 318450, "duration" : 14504.999966025352 }

is it possible to display only all msisdn number which have greater duration compare to Previous month ?

Comment: @dilshad Yes. Just remove the specific MSISDN  value from the `$match` and place it as one of the fields in the composite `_id` field in the `$group`. There will be pairs that you could additionally break down by an additional `$group` pushing each month into an array. You should give it a try first and you can always ask another question if you get stuck.

Comment: i gave already many tries 
 `
db.CDR.aggregate([ { $match : { traffic : "Data" }},{"$group" : {  
           "_id" : {  
                "Msisdn" : "$msisdn",  
                "Month" : "$date"  
           },  
 {"$project": {
        "msisdn": 1,
        "month": { "$month": "$Date" }               
    }},
     {"$sort": { "month": 1 }},

     
    {"$project": {
        "msisdn": 1,
        "Date": 1,}}
      }  
 }])
`

Comment: @dilshad Hopefully the additional information should give you more insight into this.

Comment: @Niel i Also Tried with this code <code> <br/> match={"$match" :{ "Date" : { "$gt" : new Date(2014,2,1) },{ traffic : "Data" }}};
proj1={"$project" : {"_id" : 0,"Date" : 1,"msisdn" : 1,"h" : {"$hour" : "$Date"},"m" : {"$minute" : "$Date"}, "s" : {"$second" : "$Date"},"ml" : {"$millisecond" : "$Date"}}};
group={"$group" : {"_id" : {"msisdn" : "$msisdn",  "date" : "$Date"},"Total Duration" : {  "$sum" : "$duration"   },  "Count" : {"$sum" : 1  }  } };
db.CDR.aggregate(match, proj1, proj2, group)
<code/>

Comment: proj2={"$project" : {"_id" : 0,"msisdn" : 1, "Date" : {"$subtract" : ["$Date",{"$add" : [ "$ml",{"$multiply" : ["$s",1000] },{"$multiply" : ["$m",60,1000]},{ "$multiply" : [  "$h",60,60,1000]}]}]}}};

Comment: @Niel i want to compare data 1 month to another month thats my task.

Comment: @dilshad Have you even looked at the additional code? The end result is one document per the things that make sense to group based on the data in your question. The selection is "two months", so the end stage produces an array containing the data for each month by the grouping. You cannot `$subtract` one array element from another in the aggregation pipeline. You can do silly things to make the values in one element "negative" and then `$group` again using `$sum` on those values. But that is silly, so just do that in client code where it is simple.

Comment: @Niel i m doing it on Dummy Server.