# How to compare value with the prior value of same field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing an aggregation where I sum all the sales by month (`createdAt`), and I'm trying to calculate the variation between the prior value.

How to compare value with the prior value of same field in MongoDB?

```
[
      {"$addFields": { "createdAt": {"$convert": { "input": "$createdAt", "to": "date", "onError": null}}}},

      {"$addFields": {"createdAt": {"$cond": {"if": { "$eq": [{"$type": "$createdAt" }, "date"]},
              "then": "$createdAt", "else": null}}}},

      {"$addFields": {"__alias_0": {"year": {"$year": "$createdAt" }, "month": {"$subtract": [{ "$month": "$createdAt"}, 1] } } }},

      { "$group": { "_id": { "__alias_0": "$__alias_0" }, "__alias_1": {"$sum": 1 }}},
      { "$project": {"_id": 0, "__alias_0": "$_id.__alias_0", "__alias_1": 1}},
      { "$project": {"group": "$__alias_0", "value": "$__alias_1", "_id": 0 }}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is It possible to compare two Months Data in single Collection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963788/is-it-possible-to-compare-two-months-data-in-single-collection-in-mongodb)

Comment: Not really, Because what I need is to calculate the variation between one period and its previus period for all periods. I know how to group by period but I dont know how to calculate this variation.  

At the end I need to prepare a table like this: month (or year or week) / quantity / variation prior month